Testing endpoint with rest assured
I am trying to test an endpoint that I have using rest assured with quarkus.
the endpoint is like this:
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/check/{anagram}")
    fun getAnagrams(@PathParam("anagram") anagram: String): Response {
        val anagrams = service.getCorrespondentAnagrams(anagram) ?: emptySet()
        return Response.ok(anagrams).build()
    }

while the test is like this:
@Test
fun `getAnagrams with existing anagram`() {
    anagramService.validateAnagramAndSave("listen", "silent")
    given()
        .pathParam("anagram", "listen")
        .`when`()
        .get("/anagram/check/{anagram}")
        .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo(setOf("silent")))
}

the problem is this test case is producing the following error:
1 expectation failed.
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: <[silent]>
  Actual: [silent]

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: <[silent]>
  Actual: [silent]

the question is how to get exact response to match the expected side and lose these '<' '>'

I have tried a lot of workarounds for the body method to set a working matcher but failed. I also have used the one in the answer above but also failed.
this workaround worked for me, it is far from ideal but this is what I managed to get, my conclusion, I would never use rest assured every on production level with such inconsistency
the workaround:
@Test
fun `getAnagrams with existing anagram`() {
    anagramService.validateAnagramAndSave("listen", "silent")
    val response = given()
        .pathParam("anagram", "listen")
        .`when`()
        .get("/anagram/check/{anagram}")
        .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .extract().response()
    assertTrue(response.body.asString().equals("[silent]"))
}


I believe that despite your controller uses Set as an internal collection type, RestAssured deserializes it to List.
Try to change your assertion to:
body("", Matchers.equalTo(listOf("silent")));


sadly, this gives a parse exception

Which exception exactly? I tested this on mock endpoint and no problems occurred.
